# PDFTron is throwing crunch file error

Tags: android, pdftron

I am using `PDFTron` in my android project. First as per `PDFtron SDK's` gudeline i run their sample project on my Mac and it is running fine over there but when same project i want to run on my PC(Windows10) it is throwing `.png file can not Crunch error`

Comment: Can you post the full exception message, and any stack trace. Plus, PDFNet version, IDE used, any other details.

Comment: Thanks Ryan..but my issue got resolved . Actually one stupid mistake was there,as windows cant accept long path means characters more than 256 so i just fragmented one more Drive and pasted my project over there. So that became short path and issue resolved.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer then, so this question can get answered. Or I suppose delete this if you don't think it will be helpful for others. Though seems to me it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows can't accept long path means characters more than 260 so i just fragmented one more Drive and pasted my project over there. So that became short path and issue resolved.